# How to put files and delete them straight after by means of SFTP in a Bash script?

Tags: bash, sftp

**Brief:**

I have a directory where files are dropped arbitrarily in server A. I want to dump these files into server B and delete them from server A.

**Background:**

I would like write an Bash script where the code iterates through each file, `put`s the file across to server B, and deletes it straight after. This will be ammended to the `cron` and called hourly to scrape the files across to server B

**Code:**

The code I have attempted is:

```
#!/bin/bash

MY_SCRIPT_NAME=`basename "$0"`
PATH_TO_METRICS='/home/some/directory'

if pidof -o %PPID -x $MY_SCRIPT_NAME > /dev/null; then
    echo "$MY_SCRIPT_NAME already running; exiting"
    exit 1
fi

sftp -i my_priv_key -oPort=12345 user@12.123.123.123 <<EndOfTransfer
cd $PATH_TO_METRICS
for filename in $PATH_TO_METRICS; do
   PUT "$filename"
   rm "$filename"
done

EndOfTransfer
```

**Relevant Research:**

- [Execute command in sftp connection through script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/315050/execute-command-in-sftp-connection-through-script)
- [FTP file transfer, loop through a directory and copy old files](https://serverfault.com/questions/676067/ftp-file-transfer-loop-through-a-directory-and-copy-old-files)

**Question:**

How does one iterate through files in a given a directory and use sftp to put each of the files across to another server, and delete the file if a successful transfer has happened?

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand `<<EOF` and `EOF`

In the below example `<<EOF` after the sftp command has the meaning, pass everything to the sftp program as standard input untill you get to EOF (End Of File).

So you could easily modify your script with this and get it working.

```
sftp YourSftpServer <<EOF
put YourFile
exit
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this that are much easier than using `sftp` itself, since you're using SSH in either case. You only *need* to use SFTP if you're actually running an "old school" SFTP server. If Server A/B are actually Linux machines, just use `rsync` or `scp`

```
rsync --remove-source-files -r /home/some/directory user@ServerB:/somewhere/else
```

This will copy all the files and has much better performance than `sftp` commands or `scp` since they typically open/close many connections. `rsync` will open a single connection, check to see what needs to be transfered, then transfer it all without fragmented connections.

If for whatever reason you *need* to pass your private key or use custom ports to SSH you can pass the `-e "ssh -i foo.key -p 1234"` to `rsync` and it will use those keys.